# Where is the "One-sentence NPCs" collection?

Tags: npc, online-resources

A while ago ChattyDM and someone else ran a couple contests where people submitted one-line NPCs. The collection of submissions was free to download, but now that I want to use it my google-fu has failed me and I can't find it anymore.

Where is the one-sentence NPC collection?

Comment: Why not just tweet ChattyDM?

Comment: Because if google is failing at this, it should be here! …Also I just plain didn't think of it. :)

Comment: **SevenSided** hit the nail on the head (y u no accept your answer?). This list has been providing me with ideas on-the-spot! ever since I found it (last Wednesday). [I wander what similar lists could be constructed...](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18329/as-a-gm-what-aids-could-i-use-to-create-adventure-scenes-on-the-spot)

Comment: @Vorac Isn't the collection great? (Because the delay required before accepting a self-answer made me forget to come back here and do it. Thanks for the reminder!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the PDF is hosted at RoleplayingTips.com (Johnn Four's famous site), but it doesn't appear to be *linked* from anywhere on the site or ChattyDM's blog. I eventually found the direct link via a site-search with Google:

- [One Sentence NPCs](http://www.roleplayingtips.com/downloads/onesentencenpcs.pdf) (PDF)

The problem seems to be that I was searching for "**one sentence NPCs**" (plural) when all the relevant blog posts were about the "**one sentence NPC** contest" (singular), not to mention the PDF simply not being linked-to from anywhere anymore.

Answer (score 9):

These look promising:

[Musings of the Chatty DM](http://critical-hits.com/2008/06/22/new-contest-the-one-sentence-npc/)

[Generator at Roleplayingtips](http://www.roleplayingtips.com/one-sentence-npc-generator/)

[More from Roleplayingtips](http://www.roleplayingtips.com/readissue.php?number=407#tips)

[One more from 'tips](http://www.roleplayingtips.com/readissue.php?number=406)

Comment: That leads me to [One Sentence NPC Update](http://critical-hits.com/2008/07/18/one-sentence-npc-update/), which talks about posting the PDF on the site soon, but site-search shows nothing after that post. Thanks for the lead!